# Clicking on content tab routing to different page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have the following state using `angular-ui-router` module and I am currently at the url `http://localhost:3000/#/bar/87023/` where `87023` is the value of `a`.

```
.state('foo', {
    url: '/bar/:a/:b',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/zoo.tpl.html',
            controller: 'XCtrl'
        },

        'purr@foo': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/zing.html',
            controller: 'YCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

On the `zing.html` page I have 4 tabs as following:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab">
            Zoo Details </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab">
            Pricing </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab">
            Reviews </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_1_4" data-toggle="tab">
            Something interesting </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab_1_1">
                //tab_1_1 content
            </div>                
            <div id="tab_1_2">
                //tab_1_2 content
            </div>
            <div id="tab_1_3" >
                //tab_1_3 content
            </div>            
            <div id="tab_1_4" >
                //tab_1_4 content
            </div>
</div>
```

When I click on `tab_1_1` or any of the tabs, I am taken to the `http://localhost:3000/#/` page. Could somebody help me understand why am I having this issue and how to resolve this? I want to be on the same page (`http://localhost:3000/#/bar/87023/`) and be able to see the content of the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting to index because `href` attribute changes the hash of browser, which is listened by angularJS's ngRoute.

Use `data-target` attribute instead of `href`

Here's a example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/12/)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot. Could it any chance also show the cursor pointing at the text? Just like when it shows when its around the text but within the tab?